# "Hello world" web app and Glassfish crash: address already in use: 8080

Tags: linux, netbeans, glassfish, port

From Netbeans 6.9.1 I chose to include Glassfish 3 on install.  I then created a new web application and selected JSF 2.0, so Netbeans created a "hello world" type app to start from.  However, running it brings up errors, but it's better now that I've modified glassfish a bit.  However, why is there still a database problem when I'm not even using a database?

now I'm getting:

glassfish:

```
Mar 2, 2011 8:49:36 PM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain main
INFO: Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
Welcome to Felix
================
INFO: Perform lazy SSL initialization for the listener 'http-listener-2'
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o - Wed Mar 02 20:50:51 PST 2011
INFO: Starting Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o - Wed Mar 02 20:50:51 PST 2011
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 1122ms listening on port 7676
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 1606ms listening on port 8181
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 1821ms listening on port 8081
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 1491ms listening on port 3700
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 1537ms listening on port 4848
INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 (22) startup time : Felix(67028ms) startup services(17874ms) total(84902ms)
INFO: Binding RMI port to *:8686
INFO: JMXStartupService: Started JMXConnector, JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://tleilax.servebeer.com:8686/jndi/rmi://tleilax.servebeer.com:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Hibernate Validator bean-validator-3.0-JBoss-4.0.2
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.18-o started in: 266ms listening on port 8081
INFO: Using com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate as the delegate
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] started
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = /tmp/fileinstall-8585686048027063971, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: Installed /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/osgi-web-container.jar
INFO: Installed /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/org.apache.felix.fileinstall-autodeploy-bundles.cfg
INFO: Installed /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/org.apache.felix.scr.jar
INFO: {felix.fileinstall.poll (ms) = 5000, felix.fileinstall.dir = /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/bundles, felix.fileinstall.debug = 1, felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start = true, felix.fileinstall.tmpdir = /tmp/fileinstall-3996754497384347726, felix.fileinstall.filter = null}
INFO: Started bundle: file:/home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/osgi-web-container.jar
INFO: Started bundle: file:/home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/org.apache.felix.scr.jar
INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
INFO: Security startup service called
INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
INFO: Realm admin-realm of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
INFO: Realm file of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm successfully created.
INFO: Realm certificate of classtype com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm successfully created.
INFO: Security service(s) started successfully....
INFO: Total number of available updates : 59
INFO: Available updates : 
glassfish-full-incorporation 3.1,0-43:20110215T074016Z Tue Feb 15 07:40:16 PST 2011
glassfish-web-incorporation 3.1,0-43:20110215T074014Z Tue Feb 15 07:40:14 PST 2011
glassfish-web-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154415Z Sun Feb 13 15:44:15 PST 2011
glassfish-ejb-lite-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154350Z Sun Feb 13 15:43:50 PST 2011
pkg-java 1.122,0-52.2817:20110218T204119Z Fri Feb 18 20:41:19 PST 2011
glassfish-ejb-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154345Z Sun Feb 13 15:43:45 PST 2011
glassfish-gui-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154326Z Sun Feb 13 15:43:26 PST 2011
glassfish-nucleus-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154338Z Sun Feb 13 15:43:38 PST 2011
javadb-core 10.6.2.1,0-1:20101213T185842Z Mon Dec 13 18:58:42 PST 2010
javadb-client 10.6.2.1,0-1:20101213T185835Z Mon Dec 13 18:58:35 PST 2010
jersey 1.5,0-1.0:20110215T072802Z Tue Feb 15 07:28:02 PST 2011
mq-core 4.5,0-29.2:20110210T074434Z Thu Feb 10 07:44:34 PST 2011
glassfish-jdbc-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154422Z Sun Feb 13 15:44:22 PST 2011
glassfish-full-profile 3.1,0-43:20110215T074029Z Tue Feb 15 07:40:29 PST 2011
glassfish-upgrade-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154456Z Sun Feb 13 15:44:56 PST 2011
glassfish-jca-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154405Z Sun Feb 13 15:44:05 PST 2011
javadb-common 10.6.2.1,0-1:20101213T185828Z Mon Dec 13 18:58:28 PST 2010
glassfish-common-full-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154354Z Sun Feb 13 15:43:54 PST 2011
glassfish-web-profile 3.1,0-43:20110215T074022Z Tue Feb 15 07:40:22 PST 2011
glassfish-common-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154451Z Sun Feb 13 15:44:51 PST 2011
glassfish-jts-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154359Z Sun Feb 13 15:43:59 PST 2011
glassfish-jms-l10n 3.1,0-41.1:20110213T154409Z Sun Feb 13 15:44:09 PST 2011
glassfish-corba 3.1.0,0-27:20110215T071130Z Tue Feb 15 07:11:30 PST 2011
glassfish-jms 3.1,0-43:20110215T072339Z Tue Feb 15 07:23:39 PST 2011
mq-locale 4.5,0-29.2:20110210T074528Z Thu Feb 10 07:45:28 PST 2011
mq-server 4.5,0-29.2:20110210T074445Z Thu Feb 10 07:44:45 PST 2011
mq-bin-sh 4.5,0-29.2:20110210T074442Z Thu Feb 10 07:44:42 PST 2011
metro 2.1,0-30:20110215T073257Z Tue Feb 15 07:32:57 PST 2011
glassfish-cmp 3.1,0-43:20110215T072715Z Tue Feb 15 07:27:15 PST 2011
mq-bin-exe 4.5,0-29.2:20110210T105419Z Thu Feb 10 10:54:19 PST 2011
glassfish-ejb 3.1,0-43:20110215T072446Z Tue Feb 15 07:24:46 PST 2011
glassfish-common-full 3.1,0-43:20110215T072130Z Tue Feb 15 07:21:30 PST 2011
glassfish-appclient 3.1,0-43:20110215T073837Z Tue Feb 15 07:38:37 PST 2011
mq-config-gf 4.5,0-29.2:20110210T074525Z Thu Feb 10 07:45:25 PST 2011
glassfish-grizzly-full 1.9.31,0-1:20110215T070725Z Tue Feb 15 07:07:25 PST 2011
glassfish-management 3.1,0-43:20110215T071037Z Tue Feb 15 07:10:37 PST 2011
glassfish-hk2 3.1,0-43:20110215T070538Z Tue Feb 15 07:05:38 PST 2011
glassfish-upgrade 3.1,0-43:20110215T071009Z Tue Feb 15 07:10:09 PST 2011
glassfish-jts 3.1,0-43:20110215T072233Z Tue Feb 15 07:22:33 PST 2011
glassfish-corba-base 3.1.0,0-27:20110215T070738Z Tue Feb 15 07:07:38 PST 2011
glassfish-javahelp 2.0.2,0-1:20110215T071001Z Tue Feb 15 07:10:01 PST 2011
glassfish-scripting 3.1,0-41:20110208T202810Z Tue Feb 08 20:28:10 PST 2011
glassfish-nucleus 3.1,0-43:20110215T070659Z Tue Feb 15 07:06:59 PST 2011
glassfish-jpa 3.1,0-43:20110215T071106Z Tue Feb 15 07:11:06 PST 2011
glassfish-ejb-lite 3.1,0-43:20110215T072030Z Tue Feb 15 07:20:30 PST 2011
glassfish-jcdi 3.1,0-43:20110215T072735Z Tue Feb 15 07:27:35 PST 2011
glassfish-jdbc 3.1,0-43:20110215T071818Z Tue Feb 15 07:18:18 PST 2011
glassfish-common 3.1,0-43:20110215T074007Z Tue Feb 15 07:40:07 PST 2011
glassfish-jsf 2.1.0,0-11:20110215T071155Z Tue Feb 15 07:11:55 PST 2011
glassfish-gui 3.1,0-43:20110215T071924Z Tue Feb 15 07:19:24 PST 2011
glassfish-registration 3.1,0-43:20110215T071019Z Tue Feb 15 07:10:19 PST 2011
felix 3.0.8,0-0:20110215T070355Z Tue Feb 15 07:03:55 PST 2011
glassfish-grizzly 1.9.31,0-1:20110215T070555Z Tue Feb 15 07:05:55 PST 2011
glassfish-web 3.1,0-43:20110215T071324Z Tue Feb 15 07:13:24 PST 2011
glassfish-jta 3.1,0-43:20110215T071139Z Tue Feb 15 07:11:39 PST 2011
glassfish-jca 3.1,0-43:20110215T071053Z Tue Feb 15 07:10:53 PST 2011
glassfish-cluster 3.1,0-43:20110215T070945Z Tue Feb 15 07:09:45 PST 2011
shoal 1.5.29,0-0:20110215T070911Z Tue Feb 15 07:09:11 PST 2011
glassfish-ha 3.1,0-43:20110215T070954Z Tue Feb 15 07:09:54 PST 2011
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on port 8081
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on port 8181
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on port 4848
INFO: Created virtual server server
INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO: Virtual server server loaded system default web module
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) for context '/WebApplication1'
INFO: Loading application WebApplication1 at /WebApplication1
INFO: WebApplication1 was successfully deployed in 245,397 milliseconds.
```

Java DB Database Process:

```
2011-03-03 04:49:35.249 GMT : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
2011-03-03 04:49:48.584 GMT : Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

WebApplication1 (run):

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server 3
GlassFish Server 3 is running.
In-place deployment at /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication1/build/web
Initializing...
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 minutes 35 seconds)
```

However, that "database" still on the wrong port for some reason(?).

I modified one domain.xml, but there's also one in template:

```
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ nl /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml | grep 8081
   189            <network-listener port="8081" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" />
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ ll /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/lib/templates/domain.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 12804 2010-06-08 15:37 /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/lib/templates/domain.xml
thufir@tleilax:~$
```

However, glassfish now seems to be running ok, although I would prefer it on 8080 as it would be by default.  I just don't understand why there's a database connection to, apparently, no database -- certainly not one I selected.

```
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ sudo lsof -i :1527
[sudo] password for thufir: 
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4757 thufir   27u  IPv6  46934      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:1527 (LISTEN)
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ nl /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml | grep 8081
   189            <network-listener port="8081" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" />
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ ll /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/lib/templates/domain.xml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 12804 2010-06-08 15:37 /home/thufir/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/lib/templates/domain.xml
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ sudo lsof -i :1527
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4757 thufir   27u  IPv6  46934      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:1527 (LISTEN)
thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the port 8080 has already been used by other process in your system.

try to run sudo lsof -i :8080 to see what process/service runs on that port and terminate it.

Another solution is to completely change the port number.

I had this kind of problem last time when installing Netbeans for second time a year ago but as far as I remember I had v2 glassfish and v3 beta (2 years ago).

What I did is to change the port number. Have a look at domain.xml (probably) and change the port number 8080 to something else (unoccupied port).

Comment: `thufir@tleilax:~$ 
thufir@tleilax:~$ sudo lsof -i :8080
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    7277 thufir   34u  IPv6 146037      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
thufir@tleilax:~$ `

Comment: after deleting the Derby db and editing Glkassfish Domain.xml as described, it runs :)